# Specify function to be called in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have come across this snippet in the jquery post documentation and i am not sure what it does

```
$.post("test.php", { "func": "getNameAndTime" },
 function(data){
   console.log(data.name); // John
   console.log(data.time); //  2pm
 }, "json");
```

My thinking is that test.php has a function getNameAndTime(),is this the meaning of it?.If so is this some kind of javascript pattern?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means, this script is making an asynchronous `POST` call to `test.php` page and passing a parameter called `func` with value `getNameAndTime`. then it is receiving the response from this ajax server page in a variable called `data`. I guess the respone is in `JSON` format. So in the `callback` function, It is accessing the `name` and `time` part from the JSON response and making a call to the console.debug function so that it will be printed in the firebug console.

The JSON may look like this

```
{
    "name": "Jon",
    "time": "5.30"
}
```

There may be additional items in the JSON. But for sure our code is expexting a `name` and `time` elements

You may refer the below resources to get a good understanding of what each item does

**$.post  :** [Load data from the server using a HTTP POST request.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

**JSON**  : [Javascript Object Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)- A lightweight [data-interchange format](http://www.json.org/)

Answer (score 1):

`{ "func": "getNameAndTime" }` is a JS object that is parsed to a string and then sent to the server. `test.php` handles POST requests and the data passed on to that servlet is taken from `data`. Take another look at [`jQuery.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: It is a Javascript object that is serialised to a string and sent to the server. JSON is not used.

Answer (score 1):

From [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/):

> **data** A map or string that is sent to the server with the request.

So it's simply an argument map to test.php, test.php might provide remote procedure call through this request, using that func argument.